# SF DX, cannot deploy package.xml with custom labels

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I have a VS Code project with LWC and Apex referencing custom labels.  When I attempt to deploy the meta using:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml -u testsdo-20201006
```

It fails with a message like this:

```
Error force-app\main\default\classes\TestClassLabel.cls External string does not exist: Sample_Label (3:24)
ERROR running force:source:deploy: Deploy failed.
```

This has left me unable to deploy code using the SF CLI.

I entered [a bug](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/695) for this, but this problem is really blocking me from doing my job completely.

Has anyone else been able to resolve this issue?

UPDATE

Changing my Apex code to reference the Label this way does not resolve the error:

```
String label = System.Label.Sample_Label;
```

Comment: Did you make sure the deploy contains also the label? Does the custom label section appear in the package.xml file?

Comment: Yep, the package.xml contains a reference to the custom label, and the code within the project includes the custom label itself, in the CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml file.

Comment: As temp solution you might try to create the label manually in the destination org

Comment: Yeah, I can manually create the label, but that sucks because the sfdx tooling is clearly broken.

Comment: If indeed the issue is in the sfdx then you should look for workaround, because you cannot know when it will be fixed. You can always deploy with other tools, like workbench/changeset/other

Comment: Understood.  I was able to get it working using the mdapi commands.  I'll post an update here tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and is being worked on. The known related issue is [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000scTpQAI)

The way force:source:deploy works is it first does a source convert from DX Source format to the `mdapi` source format. Looks like this is where the bug exists that it is not reading the custom label folder and files.

While the CLI engineering team works upon it, here are some potential workarounds.

1. Deploy the source using `mdapi` commands. For this, you will need to use

   ```
    export SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=<dx project path>/metadata
   ```

i.e you are setting up a flag to retain the metadata when you run the force:source:deploy command. This one is for MACOSX, you will have to tweak this to set a windows environment variable.

For regular windows terminal use

```
set SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=<dx project path>/metadata
```

For Powershell use the below command

```
$env:SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=<dx project path>/metadata
```

Unzip the file, Manually copy the label file to the metadata folder and zip the metadata folder, and use `mdapi` command to deploy.

The other alternatives

Deploy the label metadata artifact first using `mdapi` command. You will need to create a zip file for that with package XML for label and label file.

Overall this is a frustrating bug and hopefully, we will see a patch release fixing it soon.

Update:

CLI team has patched a fix for now, you can do below to get it working if you have labels in one directory

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest-rc
```

Comment: mdapi worked!  After setting the environment variable, I used these two commands:  >sfdx force:source:convert -r force-app/main/default -d c:/temp/sfdx
>sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d c:/temp/sfdx -u gs0-b2ble-win21-56 -w 60

Comment: This is fixed now if you have all labels in one directory! Check the updated answer!

Comment: I tried this a few hours ago and it worked!  Thanks!